# In how many ways can the Letters of the Alphabet be permuted such that it does not contain CAR,DOG,PUN,BYTE

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

Im using the principle on inclusion and exclusion to solve this 
There are 4 cases C1,C2,C3 ,C4 respectively

So taking the case where **CAR DOG** and **BYTE** comes together

```
n(C1^C2^C4)=20!
```

But in my book its given as 19!.
This is my explanation Taking CAR,DOG AND BYTE together total 10 letters
so (26-10)!=16!

These letters are considered as one word so (16+1)!=17!

But there will be 3 inter arrangements among them so (17+3)!=20!

Where am i doing wrong?

EDIT: You need to find 26!-N(C1UC2UC3UC4)
For this i need to calculate each permutations involving the words
so my question is regarding a particular case

Comment: There is PUN in the title but not in the rest of your question. Is AND a word in the list? (you have capitalized it like a word in the list). Overall, it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @user2943324 Please see the edit

Comment: What about PUN which is in the title but not in the body of the question?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Can't you see that There are 4 cases C1,C2,C3 ,C4 respectively im taking a particular case

Comment: No I can't see that, because you haven't written it clearly. Anyway, assuming that $C_1$ denotes the event that "CAR" occurs in the permutation, similarly $C_2$ for "DOG", $C_3$ for "PUN", and $C_4$ for "BYTE" (this is just a guess: if you mean this you should say it), does `n(C1^C2^C4)` mean "the number of permutations in which the events $C_1$, $C_2$ and $C_4$ all occur"? First define your notation carefully; else whoever is evaluating your answers won't be able to understand it, and you're likely to make mistakes too.

Comment: yes,(C1^C2^C4) mean "the number of permutations in which the events C1, C2 and C4 all occur.Edited question

Comment: Avoid incorrect equations like $26 - 10 = 16!$ and $17 + 3 = 20!$. It may be obvious to what you mean, but such sloppiness in notation is often a sign of sloppiness in thinking. In particular, it's not clear why you're considering $(17 + 3)! = 20!$.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any permutation in which all three words CAR, DOG and BYTE occur is effectively a permutation of, altogether,

- the other $26 - 10 = 16$ letters, and
- each of these three words effectively treated as a single unit.

Thus, it's a permutation of the $16 + 3 = 19$ units, and the number of such permutations is $19!$.

(It is hard to say what you are doing wrong, because it is hard to understand from your description what you are doing. In one place you seem to be treating the entire set of single words as a single unit – as if you're counting permutations in which the string "CARDOGBYTE" appears – and in other you consider $17 + 3$ for reasons that are not clear.)

Comment: Depends on how the question is interpreted. I think, for an interesting question, the POSITIONS of CAR DOG BYTE in the permutation must be taken into account. That makes it very complicated.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: This answer is indeed taking the positions of the words in the permutation, and this makes it simple as above. What is your other interpretation?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: Could you explain your comment? What is the complicated version, and what is the easy one?